# Compare two columns and return adjacent cell in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I check that a value exists in my source column, then return the adjacent cell in that source column? I have tried these functions but they're not working as I expected.

What I have now:
[image: Current table]

I am trying trying to match Column D to Column A (which is my "source" column that has all ID's). If there's a match, I want to populate Column E with the corresponding value from Column B. Similarly, I want to populate Column F with the corresponding value from Column C.

What I want:

[image: Desired table]

I looked at similar questions but wasn't able to apply those solutions successfully. Here's what I put in cell E2, but it returned an N/A error:

`=VLOOKUP(D2, A:B, 2, FALSE)`

Comment: `=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH($D2,$A:$A,0)),"")` etc

Comment: Look at the data then.  Make sure you are comparing numbers to numbers and not numbers to numbers stored as text.

Answer (score 0):

If available you could use `XLOOKUP`.

```swift
=XLOOKUP(E2, $B$2:$B$5, $C$2:$D$5, "")
```

[image]